# want to show a custom text in md-option if bind data is null

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

i didn't find any particular literals for this problem.

```
<md-option
    ng-repeat="meeting in vm.getFilteredMeetingsFromML(vm.searchTextMeeting)"
    ng-value="meeting">
    {{ meeting.meeting_title }}
</md-option>
```

if my *meeting.meeting_title* is null then i want to show "Untitled Meeting", i'm getting blank space currently

I have attached two images for better understanding

**i'm getting this the following picture.**

[image: i'm getting this currently]

**what am i want to get**

[image: what i want to get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<md-option
ng-repeat="meeting in vm.getFilteredMeetingsFromML(vm.searchTextMeeting)"
ng-value="meeting">
<span ng-if="meeting.meeting_title">
    {{ meeting.meeting_title }}
</span>
<span ng-if="!meeting.meeting_title">
    Untitled Meeting - {{meeting.meeting_id}}
</span>
```

This will be the answer if anyone want to show any custom text considering any condition in angularjs.